# How to work with the zindex property as I've added but not working

Tags: html, css, z-index

The issue is I've added z-index to the glass class as 2000 though I have tried with other higher values than the circles, the circles are always on forward of the glass.

HTML will be prvided if required

```css
.glass{
  display: flex;
  min-height: 80vh;
  min-width:50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, rgba(255,255,255,0.7),rgba(255,255,255,0.3));
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 1rem; 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2000;
  backdrop-filter: 20rem;
}
.circle1, .circle2{
  background: white;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.9),rgba(255,255,255,0.1));
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: The easiest way is to provide an example in codepen and share it here with us, or alight the code to look pretty and also provide the html

Comment: HTML is _always_ required to assess any CSS issue. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that the community can assess and help. CSS alone won't be enough to understand the context.

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu SO asks that code is provided direct in the question rather than in an external site such as codepen as external sites can disappear thus making the question useless for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The code runs just fine, the "circle" using `z-index: 2` is under the "glass" using `z-index: 2000` (you can still see it since both are partially transparent)

```css
body {background-color: red;}
.glass{
  display: flex;
  min-height: 80vh;
  min-width:50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, rgba(255,255,255,0.7),rgba(255,255,255,0.3));
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 1rem; 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2000;
  backdrop-filter: 20rem;
}
.circle1, .circle2{
  background: white;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.9),rgba(255,255,255,0.1));
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="glass"></div>
    <div class="circle1" style="top: 50px; left: 50px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```